# Certain part of my code is never executed

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, delegates, amqp

### Problem

Why my line of the code never execute: **Console.WriteLine("THIS NOT EXECUTE");**

I am not sure, is that about Try-Catch, delegate, or RabbitMQ.

Anyone had something similar?

### Progress

There is an exception(that is the reason why a certain part of my code never execute, but why that exception happened is not known):

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

### Solution

On my colleague's computer, this works fine, and that part of the code executes... Because of that, I did the following:

- deleted project locally
- clone repository again
- run project

And now everything works fine, but I would like to know what is an initial problem and why that exception happened on my computer?

### Code

```
private EventingBasicConsumer DecodeMessage()
{
    SmellDetectionReport reportMessage = new SmellDetectionReport();
    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(Channel);
    consumer.Received += (model, deliveryArguments) =>
    {
        var body = deliveryArguments.Body.ToArray();
        var jsonMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("THIS EXECUTE");
            reportMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SmellDetectionReport>(jsonMessage);
            Console.WriteLine("THIS NOT EXECUTE");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //TODO: write exc
            Console.WriteLine("exc");
            Console.WriteLine("exc");

        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("finally");
            Console.WriteLine("finally");
        }

    };
    Console.WriteLine("end");
    return consumer;
}
```

### Base info

Language: C#

Technology: RabbitMQ

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)"

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is set a breakpoint by clicking to the left of the line of code at the start of code.received and then pressing f11 to step through the code statement by statement. This will allow you to see the path the code is taking and why it doesn't reach that statement. My initial guess is that the JSON deserialization is failing and so execution moves to the catch block.

Comment: I already tried debugging, I also think something is wrong with deserialization. [Here](https://prnt.sc/10dqhwz) is the exception I am getting. Also, 100% same code work on my friend's computer...

Comment: I believe the issue was most likely a dependency that hadn't installed properly and cloning the repo and re-running it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    //TODO: write exc
    Console.WriteLine($"exc {e.Message}");
}
```

Write a catch statement like that to get better idea of exception. Also try to debug the code.

Comment: I already tried debugging. [Here](https://prnt.sc/10dqhwz) is the exception I am getting. Also, 100% same code work on my friend's computer...